# Скроллинг в ячейках таблицы при добавлении текста

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте!

Такая проблема. Есть таблица, в одной из ячеек - текст. Нужно, чтобы размеры ячейки при прибавлении текста не увеличивались, а появлялись полосы прокрутки.

Answer (score 1):

пробовали применить к ячейки таблицы свойство `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: Спасибо!
Вот что мне было нужно:
Вот вариант, который был нужен:
<div style="height: 350px; overflow-x: auto;" id="div">
Все работает!